# Adding Julia to PATH caused others to be knocked off the PATH || Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, julia, homebrew

I had a perfectly working copy of Anaconda (with Spyder at python 3.7). I installed Julia and added Julia to PATH, to be able to run it from terminal using the following command (from this source - https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Getting_started):

```
ln -fs "/Applications/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia" /usr/local/bin/julia
```

This has had following effects:

**A)** I can no longer use

```
conda update conda
```

However, Anaconda / Spyder are working fine - on their own.

**B)** The default Python version on Mac has been set back to 2.7 - the one that comes with Mac

**C)** typing

```
python3
```

in the terminal results in,

```
-bash: python3: command not found
```

but Python 3 is installed.

**D)** Running the following command at terminal, results in

```
ls /usr/local/bin/python

ls: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Further, running following command,

```
sudo find / -iname python
```

results in a very long list with "python" in the name (including folders).

**E)** it has caused homebrew installation to break. Typing

```
brew upgrade
```

results in,

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

Also, typing

```
cd /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
```

results in,

```
-bash: cd: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew: No such file or directory
```

**F)** Typing the sudo command e.g the below one:

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

results in the following message:

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

**I have searched for solutions but to no avail.**

It seems that, essentially, the terminal based stuff using PATH has been wrecked.

How can I repair all of the above?

Thanks in advance.

=================

**Edit / update -**

1) Just rebooted the computer and on relaunching the terminal, I get the following message:

```
-bash: export: `/users/<user_name>/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin': not a valid identifier
```

2) Now, even python command in the terminal is not being recognised. Typing

```
python
```

in the terminal, results in

```
-bash: python: command not found
```

Comment: What is the content of `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Also, to be precise here, you did not add Julia to Path but created a symbolic link instead. Adding to Path would be something like `export PATH="/Applications/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/:${PATH}"`

Comment: @FlyingTeller - following is the output.

    -bash: /usr/local/bin: is a directory

Comment: @crstnbr - I had done that as well !!

Comment: @Longshort that is not the content of the directory. Is there anythin still in the directory?

Comment: And can you check the value of your `PATH` variable

Comment: @FlyingTeller - apologies! Guess, I am just too tense. Yes, there are 708 items in that directory. But, I can't get the "ls" command to work. I had to get the details from finder.

Comment: @FlyingTeller - The value of the PATH variable is 

    /Applications/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/:

Seems, while adding Julia to the PATH, I may have passed a command that caused the original PATH to be overwritten.

I got the above value using 

    echo $PATH

If I use just

    $PATH

I get the following:

    -bash: /Applications/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/:: No such file or directory

Comment: Youa re correct, you have overwritten your `PATH` variable. You probably forgot to add `:${PATH}` at the end of your `export` command.

Comment: @FlyingTeller - Ok, so, can I just add back the original path and that will sort it out?

If yes, what should the command be. 

I am not an expert user and would need help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you added the `export` to your `bashrc`? Just delete it from there and restat the terminal/reboot your system

Comment: So, I just added the original path back to the PATH. This seems to have solved the homebrew issue. Python and python3 are back.

    Conda update conda 

is still not working.

Comment: Calm down. First things first. Type this command in your terminal so that we know what your PATH is set to.      Type '    set | grep "^PATH"   '

Comment: @StevenSiew - Thanks!

The output is ---

    PATH=/users/<user_name>/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/:/Applications/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/:

===============

As I had mentioned, I had added back the original path.

Answer (score 2):

Lets explain how the PATH are set when you startup/boot your Mac

1 . The OSX looks at the file /etc/paths and the content of the file is

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

2 . So the OSX builds the environment variable PATH as

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

3 . Next OSX looks at all the files in the subdirectory /etc/paths.d/ and there is one file called 40-XQuartz and the content of the file is

```
/opt/X11/bin
```

4 . So the OSX builds the environment variable PATH as

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

5 . Next the OSX looks at my .bash_profile file at /Users/ssiew/.bash_profile and please note that ssiew is my username. Your username would be different. The file has the following lines

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/ssiew/bin
```

6 .  So the OSX builds the environment variable PATH as

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/ssiew/bin
```

7 . The end

So when you type 'julia' on the terminal/commandline the OSX first look for the file

```
/usr/bin/julia
```

and if the file exists then it executes it but if it does not exists, it looks for the file

```
/bin/julia
```

and if the file exists then it executes it but if it does not exists, it looks for the file

```
/usr/sbin/julia
```

and if the file exists then it executes it but if it does not exists, it looks for the file

```
/sbin/julia
```

and if the file exists then it executes it but if it does not exists, it looks for the file

```
/usr/local/bin/julia
```

and if the file exists then it executes it but if it does not exists, it looks for the file

```
/opt/X11/bin/julia
```

and if the file exists then it executes it but if it does not exists, it looks for the file

```
/Users/ssiew/bin/julia
```

and if the file exists then it executes it but if it does not exists, it just gives up finally.

As for you because you have a symbolic link at

```
ln -fs "/Applications/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia" /usr/local/bin/julia
```

it will find the symbolic link file at /usr/local/bin/julia and get redirected to /Applications/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, @Steven Siew.

Comment: How does this explain the problems encountered by the OP?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing /users/username/ with $HOME/ in your PATH

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, I had broken the PATH variable while trying to get Julia to launch from terminal - just a reflection of my lack of understanding of the PATH variable.

I was able to restore the homebrew, python / python3 using the help offered by @FlyingTeller @crstbr and @Steven Siew.

Thank you!

I had to just add pack the original path back to the .bash_profile file.

Nonetheless, conda issue proved illusive. Eventually, even that was solved by changing the path in .bash_profile file. The relevant path is:

```
export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

ignoring the following:

```
/users/<user-name>/<remaining_path-to-anaconda>/bin:$PATH
```

or

```
~/<remaining_path-to-anaconda>/bin:$PATH
```

**I guess, it will be helpful if one first figures out the exact location of anaconda folder.**

I still need to work out the issue regarding making anaconda python the default python in terminal. I will figure that out as well. As of now, I am up and working! :-)

and, the best part is Julia - the tormentor - can be launched from the terminal! ;-)

**Thanks again everyone for your support.**

cheers!!